# N size for not being considerated leverage

Tags: r

Suposse I have a dataset with two variables x and y, with the purpose to run a linear regression y ~ x.
We have all x values equal and y varying between 1 and 10.
For example (in R code):

```
x <- rep(100, 50)
y <- runif(50, 1, 10)
```

If I add a new value, being x value 75, this new value will be considerated a leverage:

```
x <- c(x, 75)
y <- c(y, runif(1, 1, 10))
fit <- lm(y ~ x)
im <- influence.measures(fit)
tail(im$is.inf)
```

How many 75's I need to add to the dataset for not being considerated a leverage?

Is there any R package that returns that critical N size?

Edit after @RuiBarradas comments

hatvalues with 51 observations (50 100's and 1 75) are:

```
> im$infmat[, 6]
   1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10   11   12   13   14   15   16 
0.02 0.02 0.02 0.02 0.02 0.02 0.02 0.02 0.02 0.02 0.02 0.02 0.02 0.02 0.02 0.02 
  17   18   19   20   21   22   23   24   25   26   27   28   29   30   31   32 
0.02 0.02 0.02 0.02 0.02 0.02 0.02 0.02 0.02 0.02 0.02 0.02 0.02 0.02 0.02 0.02 
  33   34   35   36   37   38   39   40   41   42   43   44   45   46   47   48 
0.02 0.02 0.02 0.02 0.02 0.02 0.02 0.02 0.02 0.02 0.02 0.02 0.02 0.02 0.02 0.02 
  49   50   51 
0.02 0.02 1.00
```

What i want to know is how many 75's i have to add so that 75 are not considered leverages, because I'm deleting observations with high leverage from my analysis.

This have to be done programatically for over 1000 cases.

Comment: Aren't you assuming that `N` exists? The regression line is an average line and the mean has a known breakdown point of 1. It is always possible to make the mean be equal to any *chosen* value.

Comment: @RuiBarradas if i add enough x observations with value 75, won't i get a regression line?

Comment: Are you looking for `hatvalues(fit)`?

Comment: @RuiBarradas yes, I'm using hatvalues(fit) (same results as im$infmat[, 6] in my example). I'm editing the question to clarify it.

Comment: Leverage depends both on the size of the dataset and the "distance" between the point in question and the other points in the dataset.  Thus, there cannot be a single N for which leverage is "not a problem" vs leverage "is a problem".  As with many things, it's a matter of judgment, not a simple dichotomy.  Deleting observations which don't fit your model is a flawed approach.  You should adapt your model to accurately reflect your data, not the other way round.

Comment: "because I'm deleting observations with high leverage from my analysis" That's not something I'd recommend. If you have high leverage points, robust regression approaches can help.

Comment: Actually, my script compare models with and without high leverages and remove them if, according to some rules, I have to. With "because I'm deleting observations with high leverage from my analysis" I was only trying to simplify the question. So my problem is not wether to remove or not observations with high leverage. Sometimes a set of data has multiple observations of only 1 value and only 1 observation of another x value, so I need to know how many of that another x value will be necessary fot not having a high leverage. Please don't assume my approach is inappropriate

Comment: Looks like you should take this to stats.stackexchange.com. It's not a programming question.

Answer (score 0):

Well I don't think anyone is trying to question your approach just point out that as you drop high leverage rows more will appear. potentially with even higher leverage.

But best to simply arm you to do what you want.  Here's a function that will take a dataset, a regression formula, and how_deep you want to go.

We'll apply it to `mtcars` and say that we want to make sure we have 27 rows of 32 left which means `how_deep` = 27.  You get back a vector of cars.  Initially the Lincoln has the highest leverage when you eliminate it, it's now a Chrysler with what is actually higher leverage.  Hopefully your data will be much different

```r
recursive_leverage <- function(data, formula, how_deep) {
   while (nrow(data) >= how_deep) {
      data$hatval <- hatvalues(lm(formula = formula, data = data))
      print(paste(rownames(data[which.max(data$hatval),]), max(data$hatval)))
      data <- data[-which(data$hatval == max(data$hatval)),]
   }
}
recursive_leverage(mtcars, mpg ~ wt + disp, 27)
#> [1] "Lincoln Continental 0.198891254526384"
#> [1] "Chrysler Imperial 0.240276382749128"
#> [1] "Cadillac Fleetwood 0.274528186610731"
#> [1] "Lotus Europa 0.224979770471144"
#> [1] "Honda Civic 0.223347867723116"
#> [1] "Ford Pantera L 0.21141405715464"
```

Comment: Thak you Chuck, It's not exactly what I was looking for but I will follow that recursive example.